# Is dplyr::inner_join order preserving?

Tags: r, dplyr

The code below makes dplyr::inner_join look to preserve order of the first data frame.  However, I can't tell from [the docs](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/join.html) if that's guaranteed.  Is it?  Got a ref?

```
library(dplyr)

df1 <- data.frame(num=c(2,1), val1=c('b', 'a'))
df2 <- data.frame(num=c(1,2), val2=c('c', 'd'))

> df1 %>% inner_join(df2, by=c('num'))
  num val1 val2
1   2    b    d
2   1    a    c
```

Comment: I guess you're looking for mathematical "proof" (so to speak) that order is clearly/intentionally preserved, or mathematical assertion that it is not necessarily preserved. If you don't get sufficient response here for that, it might be necessary to raise an issue to get a canonical answer from the `*_join` authors. Lacking that ... I'd treat it like most SQL queries/joins, where order is not assured unless you specify `order by` in SQL or `arrange` in dplyr. (That's how I treat it, though I do not recall seeing a change in 1st-frame order on `left_join`.)

Comment: By Hadley [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/manipulatr/OuAPC4VyfIc/Qnt8mDfq0WwJ): "The advantages of the `dplyr` [join] versions over `merge` are [...] rows are kept in existing order". But again, "guaranteed"

Comment: Sounds like the intention expressed in a Google Group is to be order preserving, but there's no promise in the docs themselves, so I shouldn't rely on it. If someone submits that as an answer, I'll accept it.